# Android Studio TMDB dependency

Tags: android, gradle, themoviedb-api

I'm trying to add TMDB wrapper (com.omertron:themoviedbapi:4.0) Into my Android studio project. I added it through the edit libraries and dependencies. But when I run the app after adding it I get some error messages

This is the Error I am receiving

[image]

These are the dependencies

[image]

I added the dependencies for the jackson annotations, core, and databind but the still show up in the error. Should I add the jar files rather than the library dependency?

Comment: I added the jackson dependencies as file dependencies (jar files) which got rid of those error messages. But now i get this error message                    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your build.gradle

```
android {
packagingOptions {
exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'

}
}
```